# How to programmatically enable and disable a button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a button to be disabled initially. Once a condition is met, I want to enable the button. I tried the below and the button is not getting enabled.

```
<button class="search btn right-align search-button disabled" id="view-btn">
Hello
</button>

$('#submit_query').click(function(){
document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false; 

}
```

Comment: Unless it's a typo your example tries to set the state of "myBtn" but the id truly is "view-btn"?

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery is simpler:

```js
$('#submit_query').click(function(){
$("#myBtn").attr("disabled","false"); 

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<button class="search btn right-align search-button disabled" id="myBtn">
Hello
</button>

<button id="submit_query">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your #ids match your HTML button controls and that you are bringing in jQuery.
Then to enable an element you want to do this:

```
$('#enable').click(function(){
  $("#view-btn").removeAttr("disabled"); 
});
```

and to disable:

```
$('#disable').click(function(){
  $("#view-btn").attr("disabled","true"); 
});
```

For working example:
http://jsbin.com/xigeyixoji/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<button id="myBtn" disabled>My Button</button>

<p>Click the button below to disable the button above.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()" >Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided the id for the button element is "view-btn" however the JavaScript code is using getElementById using "myBtn".

Also, the button is assigned the 'disabled' class which may or may not actually disable the button. "disabled" is a separate attribute from class.

Additionally, the JavaScript is using jQuery to assign the click handler. The standard way to use jQuery to enable a control is: 
`$("#view-btn").prop("disabled", false );`

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="search btn right-align search-button" disabled id="view_btn">
Hello
</button>

<button class="search btn right-align search-button"  id="submit_query">
click me
</button>

var myHTML = document.querySelector('#submit_query');
myHTML.onclick = function() {
console.log(1);
  document.getElementById("view_btn").disabled = false; 
};
```

relevant link : http://jsfiddle.net/765ogwf1/11/